# VisualStudio designer to automatically set GenerateMember property to false

Tags: visual-studio, user-controls, properties, windows-forms-designer

Everthing's in the title :)

I'd like VisualStudio designer to automatically set GenerateMember property to false for each Control. I would manually set it to true when needed. 
Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own controls by inheriting each class you want to use.  In the constructor, you would set that property to false.  To get them into VS's toolbox, you can right click on the toolbox and add each of your classes.  You'd have to do this for each control you want to use.  Tedious, but it's the only way I can think of to accomplish what you want.

```
public MyDropDownList : DropDownList
{
    public MyDropDownList() : base()
    {
        GenerateMember = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer is wrong in more than one way.  Controls automatically get added to the toolbox.  And this code doesn't compile, GenerateMember is not a property of a control.